# Formatação de número float em lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatação, float

Tenho um dataframe com colunas de Latitude e Longitude, no formato string

```
Atibaia['LATITUDE'].head()

140     -231,124,852,387,647
245     -231,159,749,902,692
254          -23,116,747,205
512     -231,560,912,572,211
1348         -23,115,763,607
```

Já consegui remover as vírgulas e converter pra float usando o seguinte trecho de código:

```
Atibaia['LATITUDE'] = Atibaia.loc[:,'LATITUDE'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
Atibaia['LONGITUDE'] = Atibaia.loc[:,'LONGITUDE'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
```

(Que inclusive gera o seguinte aviso: C:\Users\Ramon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

mas funciona e acabo com esse resultado:

```
Atibaia['LATITUDE'].head()

140    -2.311249e+14
245    -2.311597e+14
254    -2.311675e+10
512    -2.315609e+14
1348   -2.311576e+10
```

Entretanto preciso dos valores neste formato -> -23.1171, -46.5502 (Latitude x Longitude de Atibaia)

Como devo proceder agora? Tem uma semana que estou 'preso' nisso e não acho um jeito de contornar a situação

Answer (score 0):

Depois de alguns dias encontrei uma resposta, segue:

```
Atibaia['LATITUDE'] = atibaia.LATITUDE.str.replace(',','')
Atibaia['LATITUDE'] = atibaia['LATITUDE'].apply(pd.to_numeric) # <--- THIS!!!!!!
Atibaia['LATITUDE'].head()
```